# How to set a particular python version as default in terminal, but to keep the possibility to use another (e.g. conda) for a package

Tags: python, bash, terminal, path, conda

In order to install an external package, I had to install `conda` and activate an environment to use that external package. However, now the conda version of python is the default version:

```
$ which python
/Users/mymac/miniconda3/bin/python

$ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
```

In my `.bash_profile` the 2 versions seem to be coexisting:

```
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
alias ls='ls -GFh'

# Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/mymac/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/mymac/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/mymac/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/mymac/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi  
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

when then added the following line in my `.bashrc`

```
alias python='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
```

then I retried the previous command

```
$ which python
/Users/mymac/miniconda3/bin/python

$ python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 16:52:21) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
```

The version seemed to have changed, but the source is still the same.

Which precise commands do have to do in order to have the non-conda python version as default in terminal, but to keep the possibility to use the conda version for that particular package (by typing `source activate thepackage`)

Comment: For multiple python versions in the system. install the default python globally and add path in environment variables. While using conda install and  use the required python version from a custom path.

Comment: thanky you very much for @ArunAugustine. That's indeed exactly what I want to do. My question is more how concretely to do it exactly: could you please write the set of commands that I have to write in Terminal or lines that I have to write in my `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, delete the alias command, it will only cause you problems later when you forget that you created the alias. Then, add the conda configuration option so that the base environment is not activated by default. In your terminal, type:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

This should restore the system Python to be the first found on your path. Now, when you want to use a conda environment, simply type

```
conda activate env-name
```

and you should have access to that environment's Python. When you're done, typing

```
conda deactivate
```

will get you back to the original state. If you activated multiple environments, you may need to run `conda deactivate` several times.

Comment: Many thanks for your very clear and useful answer @darthbith. I have 2 more question: 1. are those command (`conda config --set auto_activate_base false`) saved on text file somewhere, so that I can have an overview of some of those changes at any time? 2. which ressource/website do you recommand to understand how to manage the python/conda environments from the terminal. Many thanks again for your answer

Comment: 1. Yes, by default to `~/.condarc`. 2. A lot of it is based on experience. The conda documentation is usually helpful too: https://conda.io/en/latest/